# Matplotlib:empty confusion matrix

Tags: matplotlib, confusion-matrix

Need to plot a confusion matrix with this script. By running it an empty plot appears. Seems I am close to solution. Any hint?

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

conf_arr = [[50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [3.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 47.0, 0.0], [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0]]

norm_conf = []
for i in conf_arr:
        a = 0
        tmp_arr = []
        a = sum(i,0)
        for j in i:
        tmp_arr.append(float(j)/float(a))
        norm_conf.append(tmp_arr)

plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
res = ax.imshow(array(norm_conf), cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')
cb = fig.colorbar(res)
savefig("confmat.png", format="png")
```

Thanks, I have the plot. Now, the ticks in the x-axes are very small (the graph dimension is: 3 cm x 10 cm or so). How can I enlarge them in order to have a more proportioned graph, lets say 10cm x 10 cm plot? A possible reason is that I visualize the graph as a subplot? Was not able to find the suitable literature to adjust that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to clear a current figure (`plt.clf()`) before adding a new one.

```
#plt.clf()  # <<<<< here
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the plot. Now, the ticks in the x-axes are very small (the graph dimension is: 3 cm x 10 cm or so). How can I enlarge them in order to have a more proportioned graph, lets say 10cm x 10 cm plot? Is a possible reason is that I visualize the graph as a subplot?

Comment: Why don't you make it a separate question (or google/look up the docs).

Comment: Just found a possible solution, no need for questioning...thanks